# I am unable to press the Apps button in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I recently created my first app for iOS. I have gone through all the steps in creating certificates, App ID, Profiles, etc. However, when I log in to App Store Connect I get presented with five icons, "Apps, Artists, Books, Media and Podcast Connect". "Apps" is the only button relevant to me, but when I press it, absolutely nothing happens. The same is true for "Books, Media and Podcast Connect", the only button I can press on is "Artists". Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: it is broken for me as well. 
Could you make it work again for you?

Comment: I submitted a support ticket. After a few days they fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a support ticket and the issue was resolved.